# Return types in ASP.NET MVC Actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications

Is it recommended to define specific return types for controller actions?

Or in other words since results like `JSONRESULT, VIEWRESULT` etc... derive from `ACTIONRESULT` what is the best practice in terms of specifying the return type for a controller action.

`ACTIONRESULT` or a more specific Result type.

Is there any best practice/OOAD aspect approach to this.

Comment: This is probably going to spawn debate.  I like leaving the return type to be an `ActionResult`.  It's more flexible this way.  For example, if I don't specify `JsonResult` and leave it as `ActionResult`, I can return a `JsonResult` OR an `HttpStatusCodeResult`.

Comment: But surely specifying JsonResult for example more clearly defines the intent of the action i.e you know by the definition that it is inteded to return JSON? Not that I know much about MVC, but is there any real case where you might want to return an HTML page today but a JSON object tomorrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific recommendation for that. My opinion today (I used to be more specific) is the same as Dan, because I find it easier to maintain my code that way.

Answer (score 2):

The best practise is always that to keep our method's parameters and return types the most generic types like we accept IEnumerable not an T[] and this is true for return types.